# ImageMagick command to Image::Magick code

Tags: perl, imagemagick, perlmagick

I found the following ImageMagick command in some forum and works nicely for compare images.

```
convert image1 image2 -compose Difference -composite  -format '%[fx:mean*100]' info:
```

The result is one **floating point number** and low values (like 0.5 and such) mean: the images are similar.

Using the attached images, it produces the number: `0.0419167`. (the images are very similar)

I want to use Image::Magick (perlmagick). The problem is i don't know how to achieve the same result with perlmagick. The following works, and creates the `composite`, (black image using the attached images)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Image::Magick;

my $i1 = Image::Magick->new;
$i1->Read('s1.jpg');
my $i2 = Image::Magick->new;
$i2->Read('s2.jpg');

$i1->Composite(image => $i2, compose=>'Difference');
$i1->Display();
```

The question is, how to convert the result to an number, e.g. how to achieve the

```
    ... -format '%[fx:mean*100]' info:
```

part of the above command in PerlMagick for getting only the above "number"?

Is someone want test, attaching two images:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to call

```
my $format = $iI->Fx( expression=>'mean*100' );
```

This should do the same thing as what you had on command line.

see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php) for more detailed documentation of fx in PerlMagick

( there is an example fx line on the page )

On the same page: search for @statistics.

Seems to me the mean is accessible via

```
my @stats = $i1->Statistics;
my $mean = $stats[3]; # hash would be nice, mean is 4th according to docs
print "$mean\n"; # outputs something like .0413 for me
```

Not sure if this is what you need, but that is how I found the 'mean',
whether this is precisely what fx mean does I am not certain and honestly not willing to understand the entire doc on the fx method ;)

BTW, the script I still had was based on [Randall Schwartz's post](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col50.html)

Comment: unfortunately, it returns in ImageMagick image (not a number) displayable with `$format->Display()`...

Comment: I remember faintly having had a similar problem. I shall dig for the code and get back to you

Comment: That would be great. ;) Thanx in advance. ;)

Comment: Just found the solution. ;)

Comment: yup, me too. Added a link to another script as well, which should be generally useful. Seems your answer is better, just accept it and all is well in case someone needs this

Comment: Accepting this, because i found the `Statistics` when reading the `Fx` - to what pointed me you. ;) Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer.

`Image::Magick` has the `Statistics` method, so calling:

```
my @stat = $i1->Statistics();
say Dumper \@stat
```

prints image stats for each channel, like:

```
$VAR1 = [
      '8',
      '0',
      '0.168627450980392',
      '0.0418661437908497',    <--- mean RED
      '0.0236850206077085',
      '-0.250788990333716',
      '0.312238727773058',
      '8',
      '0',
      '0.133333333333333',
      '0.0385273202614379',     <- mean GREEN
      '0.0193189321997568',
      '-0.435325792918546',
      '0.0686645009183608',
      '8',
      '0',
      '0.23921568627451',
      '0.0453563725490196',     <- mean BLUE
      '0.0301331898766906',
      '0.309072091600589',
      '0.66336367830764'
    ];
```

e.g. averaging the 3 numbers, got the wanted number: `0.0419166122004357`

```
use List::Util qw(sum)
my $s = sum @stat[3,10,17];
say $s/3;
```

From the docs: [misc methods](http://imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#miscellaneous)

> Statistics() returns the image statistics for each channel in the
>   image. The returned values are an array of depth, minima, maxima,
>   **mean**, standard deviation, kurtosis, skewness, and entropy values in
>   RGB, CMYK, RGBA, or CMYKA order (depending on the image type).